# Settings to change when upgrading from Smart Extruder to Smart Extruder+

Tags: fdm, pla, makerbot, slicing

I am optimizing a collection of slicing profiles and in the process of upgrading some profiles from the classic Makerbot Smart Extruder to the new Smart Extruder+.

What are the parameters that should be changed with the new extruder?
Are there any params to which the new extruder is more "sensitive"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "sensitive" params here. You just need to set it up like the regular Smart Extruder.

Like the original design, the Smart Extruder+ is supposed to make Replicator printers simpler to use, more reliable, and more future-proof. It automatically detects when the printer's filament runs out and pauses the job, notifying users via a desktop or mobile app. It also can be quickly swapped out upon wearing out or becoming obsolete.

Additional improvements include faster print start up and refined build plate leveling, the process of calibrating a 3D printer. The smart sensors within the extruder have been enhanced for better performance and to streamline the printing process from start to completion.

Improved components include:

- A better thermal management system
- Extended PTFE tube to feed the filament into the nozzle
- Faster print start up
- Refined build plate leveling and calibration

The enhanced smart sensors are a big part of the story here though in that they allow for better speed, along with savings on the bottom line too, keeping users informed about print status from beginning to end, whether from the PC or mobile app.